# Rails, is it possible to change the color depending on the value of an column of a table containing balance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

index.html.erb

```
    <% balance = 0 %>

    <table align="center" width="50%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="5">  
        <tr>
            <td>Amount</td>
            <td>Discount</td>
            <td>Paid</td>
            <td>Balance</td>
        </tr>   

<% @statements.each do |statement| %>

  <tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

    <td class="col-1"><%= statement.date %></td>
    <td class="col-3"><%= statement.description %></td>

    <td class="col-1"><%= number_with_precision(statement.amount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(statement.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(statement.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


<% balance += statement.amount.to_f - statement.discount.to_f - statement.paid.to_f %>

        <% color = balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

        <td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

</tr>

    <% end %>

  </table>

<center><p><b><%= number_to_currency(balance.abs, :unit => 'AED ', :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></b></p></center>
```

I would like to have change of colour of balance entity that is when balance is positive it must show black and when goes negative it must show in red.

Here is my application.css.scss

```
.pos { color: #000; }
.neg { color: #f00; }
```

I am not getting the result as expected.

Please see the result as below;

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KuvH.jpg)

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVFrc.jpg)

Comment: yes, it is possible. When you load the page however, what do you see?

Comment: Yeah, you can review the result by clicking the Sample data link , which is present at the bottom of the post.

Comment: After all, I cannot find the solution.Please guide...

Comment: haha...:) I think it's working!. Notice that at the point you got a negative balance, `-664.0`, the next row was red(the `neg` class included for it) My guess is that the looping is so fast, that the html gets compiled with previous value of `color` for class, before `<% color = balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>` finished calculating the new value for `color`

Comment: What about if you move the `balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg"` into the `td` class? like follow:  `<td class="<%= balance >= 0 ? 'pos' : 'neg' %>">` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the result is the same.

Comment: Oh... haha... At the point we are checking the value of balance, the new value of balance is yet to be computed. you should compute the new value of `balance` before checking the value for assigning classes. For easy formatting, I'll put the logic in an answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rick is right, but there is a small glitch.

As I mentioned in my comment above, the value of balance is being used to assign a class `.neg or .pos` before the new value is being calculated. This is responsible for it taking the previous `balance` value for giving it the class as shown in the attached samples.

Below is how you can compute the new value before using it to get it working correctly:

```
<% balance = 0 %>

<table align="center" width="50%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="5">  
    <tr>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Discount</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td>Balance</td>
    </tr>

    <% @statements.each do |statement| %>

    <tr>

        <td><%= statement.amount %></td>

        <td class="neg"><%= statement.discount %></td>  
        <td class="neg"><%= statement.paid %></td>

       <% balance += statement.amount.to_f - statement.discount.to_f - statement.paid.to_f %>

        <% color = balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

        <td class="<%= color %>"><%= balance  %></td>

    </tr>

    <% end %>

</table>
```

Notice that we first computed the new value of `balance` before using it in any operation. This way, at the point of assigning the class, `balance` holds the real and correct value for the current loop.

Try this and let's know what you get on the view...

Comment: Thank you very much, Finally it worked!!! Second thing I would like to show the negative balance without negative sign that is only red colour. Thank you again for your time and hard work. Keep it up!!!

Comment: You just use the `absolute` method => `.abs` on it.      2.0.0 :004 > `a = -66.55
 => -66.55 
a.abs
 => 66.55 
`

Comment: Thanks Sir, I got it.

Comment: Please find the picture link at the bottom of the post for better understanding as I just tried by myself but not able to get the result.Thank you in advance for your kind help..

Answer (score 0):

Sure, [just use CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/ehf64abk/1/):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
tr.pos { color: #000; }
tr.neg { color: #f00; }

#app/views/controller/index.html.erb
<% color = balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

<td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(statement.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>  
<td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(statement.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>
<td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(balance += statement.amount.to_f - statement.discount.to_f - statement.paid.to_f, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not providing the desired result"? Can you give me a description on what does happen?

Comment: I see the colours - what is the problem?

Comment: My cat woke up sick today. PLEASE HELP! Oh? You need more information? .... you need to provide the rendered HTML source for the page - I need to see what classes are being assigned and how they're working. Showing me a bunch of colours on a screen doesn't help

Comment: Thanks bud! Let me see

Comment: Okay firstly, you're following my answer and manually put "neg" into the first two rows. I took this from your question. If it's wrong, I have updated my answer.

Comment: The second thing is that your logic seems messed up. Again, I took this directly from your code. If *balance* is greater than or equal to 0, the class will be "pos" (black). This would be a problem if your `balance` value was wrong.

Comment: Please find the picture link at the bottom of the post for better understanding as I just tried by myself but not able to get the result.Thank you in advance for your kind help.